# Where is neurogenesis absent/uncommon in the human brain?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

I know that neurogenesis is an integral part of hippocampus, however are there parts of the brain where neurogenesis never or rarely happens? I'm assuming that any part of the brain stem does not have neurogenesis, since injuries in that area are rarely recouperated from.